# What is the downside of merging several microservices in a single monolith?

Tags: microservices

I can see the time employed in maintaining lots of microservices with functionality not independent from each other. Clients, queues, routers...a lot of stuff that maybe is not totally needed for attending the needs of conceptually simple projects. What is the downside of merging several microservices in a single monolith? If the project itself is the only consumer of most of its microservices, I think that partitioning a large app is just wasting time for the sake of following a supposedly good practise in an scenario in which does not fit.

Comment: hi Hector, since this one barely scratches any programming issue. i believe it is better to ask on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). though personally, the risk having a microservices on a single monolith will be.. if it down, everything will go down with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservices provide for set of guide lines that help you build applications which can scale easily, which are more available and which allows your team to bring around changes really fast.
Having said that, it does not really closes the gate on monoliths or any other guidelines that you want to follow while building stuff.

There will be cases when building a monolith will indeed be a better option. 
Say you are starting with some thing new, and you domain knowledge is not good. It will become really hard to break your application into services. In depth understanding of the domain is required to break services into effective smaller independent chunks.

Second could be you are doing a POC or MVP (with plans to test waters) then perhaps you can build everything as one.

With microservices, like I said you get scale, availability, maintainability and speed to make changes. There will be projects where these are not really a concern, and if they are not you can keep away from it.

Lastly, with microservices, you need to have a solid dev ops. you need to have CI/CD pipelines, you need to have monitoring, centralised logging etc, because trust me you will need it to debug stuff. It is indeed big investment and you should think what you are getting into and why you are getting into.
You should not be using it just because every one else is.